# TeXMaker doesn't recognize updates in the .bib file

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I have recently migrated from Overleaf to TeXMaker+MikTeX. 
I am writing a report for university and have to add a lot of references to the .bib file.
 When I make any change in this file, TeXMaker behaves in an odd way: It will only recognize the change if I edit the .bib file, close it and then open it again. This happens both if I edit the .bib directly through TeXMaker or if I use JabRef.

Any clues on what is going wrong?

PS: I am using the "Quick Build" option that runs pdfLaTex + BibTex + pdfLaTex(2x) + pdf Viewer.

Thanks in advance.

A minimal example:

.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Hello

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\nocite{lanczos1970variational}

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@Book{lanczos1970variational,
  title     = {The variational principles of mechanics},
  publisher = {Dover Publications},
  year      = {1970},
  author    = {Lanczos, Cornelius},
  address   = {New York},
}

@Book{milne1996theoretical,
  title     = {Theoretical hydrodynamics},
  publisher = {Dover Publications},
  year      = {1996},
  author    = {Milne-Thomson, Louis Melville},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: `bibtex` should see the latest version on disk; it should suffice to save the file without closing it. Does that not work?

Comment: Dear Michael, thanks for your attention. No, I have tried it at first but doesn't work. I remark that in overleaf such a procedure works, so I imagine that there is no problem with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is solved by putting the .bib files in the directory

```
C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bib
```

and setting the path

```
C:\localtexmf
```

in MiKTeX. The only issue is that TeXMaker stops suggesting the keys.