# Quick Build not picking up latest .bib files

Tags: bibtex, miktex

When I run the script below with Quick Build it picks up very old versions of the `.bib` file `chap2.bib` that is long since gone

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\input{chapter2}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{chap2}

\end{document}
```

I have tried many times using the {Latex, Bibtex, Latex, Latex} formula.  It makes no difference.

There's a similar question answered on 22 Nov  2017 by Danilo Gregorin to a post entitled ['TeXMaker doesn't recognize updates in the .bib file'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402485/124842), but I don't know how to set the path he suggests in MikTex.

Does this work if you set the path as suggested or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What does "Quick Build" means (only pdflatex?)? [Why does Latex/Bibtex need three passes to clear up all warnings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53235/124842).

Comment: In order to update your bibliography you will need to run `pdfLaTeX`+`BibTeX`+`pdfLaTeX`+`pdfLaTeX`, it might be your issue here. You can set your quickbuild to do that in TexMaker

Comment: Press F11, press quick build again.

Comment: F11 seems to work  (amazing solution! who would have known?) only I have to keep repeating it.. Many thanks for 'getting me off the rocks'.